# slideToggle has a rubber band effect on my ul slideToggle (jQuery help)

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive

My mobile menu has a jquery function of slideToggle when the window browser is smaller than `600p`x. However, when the icon is clicked it slides down the `ul`, but immediately slides it back up.

Here's what I'm talking about

https://jsfiddle.net/0cc4dynv/

Comment: Try This.... $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#trigger').click(function() {
          $('#nav-menu').slideToggle();
      });
      });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just comment or delete this line:

```
$(this).toggleClass('.trigger-expand').css('display', '');
```

Now if you want to change some css when the browser size is changing and is larger than `600px` use this method:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      var win = $(this); //this = window
      if (win.width() > 600) { 
         /* The window is larger than 600px 
            change you css style here */ 
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will works

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {
    $('#nav-menu').slideToggle(400, function() {
      //$(this).toggleClass('.trigger-expand').css('display', '');
    });
  });
```

Comment: But then the ul doesn't appear when I have the screen back in full width.

Comment: your menu is working. What you want now I am not getting your point.